# With felipecsl Android-ImageManager library how can I replace a cached image

Tags: android, image, caching

I am using [felipecsl Android-ImageManager library](https://github.com/felipecsl/Android-ImageManager) to download some images from one of our servers and load it in a list view. In my Android application I have a feature to change that downloaded image from app side and upload it to server.

I do know how to load the image from URL because it is well documented with the above mentioned link. What I need is to change/delete a particular cached item and replace it with my new image from Android application side.

Let me explain it further. Normally what happens is, it loads an image from the provided URL and caches it in the manager's LRU and Disk cache. Then the second time call to that same URL, if the image is already cached, fetches it from the cache even I have set a different image from my application side.

Therefore how can I either delete that URL from cache OR set the new image for the cache of that same URL.

I have tried something like below, but seems it is not working.

```
imageManager.getCacheManager().getMemoryCache().put(ImageManager.getCacheKeyForJob(myUrl, jobOptions), bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not really supported by the library. If you need to do this kind of more advanced cache management, you can use Picasso (https://github.com/square/picasso), where you can set your own cache manager and have more control over your cached images.

Comment: I think what I need is not doable at the moment with [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438) too.